# SQL Compare and Unity table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I have 2 table, i get problem when unity they all
tell that

**Table 1**

```
 Customer | Buyer | Usage | Item Code | Item Name | Month1 | Month2 

   A      Jirulu  Bottom    111111     Item1        100      50          
   B      Bakeyo  Top       122222     Item2        100      50        
   D      Sagero  Bottom    133333     Item3        100      50
```

**Table 2**

```
Customer | Buyer | Usage | Item Code | Item Name | Month3 | Month4 | 

   A      Jirulu  Bottom    111111     Item1        100      50      
   C      Bakeyo  Top       122222     Item2        100      50      
   D      Sagero  Bottom    133333     Item3        100      50
```

How can I get result like this:

```
Customer | Buyer | Usage | Item Code | Item Name | Month1 | Month2| Month3 | Month4 | 

   A      Jirulu  Bottom    111111     Item1        100      50      100      50    
   B      Bakeyo  Top       122222     Item2        100      50      100      50        
   C      Bakeyo  Top       122222     Item2         0        0      100      50
   D      Sagero  Bottom    133333     Item3        100      50      100      50
```

Please advice, thankyou!

Comment: Please show what you have tried and which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: i'm using SQL Server 2012 

I have tried with UNION ALL , but the result nothing so far

Answer (score 0):

Below Query will help you.

```
SELECT tab.customer, 
       tab.buyer, 
       tab.usage, 
       tab.usage, 
       tab.itemcode, 
       tab.itemname, 
       Sum(month1) AS Month1, 
       Sum(month2) AS Month2, 
       Sum(month3) AS Month3, 
       Sum(month4) AS Month4 
FROM   (SELECT customer, 
           buyer, 
           usage, 
           itemcode, 
           itemname, 
           month1, 
           month2, 
           0 AS month3, 
           0 AS month4 
    FROM   table1 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT customer, 
           buyer, 
           usage, 
           itemcode, 
           itemname, 
           0 AS month1, 
           0 AS month2, 
           month3, 
           month4 
    FROM   table2) tab 
GROUP  BY tab.customer, 
      tab.buyer, 
      tab.usage, 
      tab.usage, 
      tab.itemcode, 
      tab.itemname
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than the `UNION` already shown it's possible to `JOIN` the two table, in this case having different customer in the two table a `FULL JOIN`

```
SELECT Coalesce(t1.[Customer], t2.[Customer]) [Customer]
     , Coalesce(t1.[Buyer], t2.[Buyer]) [Buyer]
     , Coalesce(t1.[Usage], t2.[Usage]) [Usage]
     , Coalesce(t1.[Item Code], t2.[Item Code]) [Item Code]
     , Coalesce(t1.[Item Name], t2.[Item Name]) [Item Name]
     , Coalesce([Month1], 0) [Month1]
     , Coalesce([Month2], 0) [Month2]
     , Coalesce([Month3], 0) [Month3]
     , Coalesce([Month4], 0) [Month4]
FROM   Table1 t1
       FULL JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Customer = t2.Customer 
                          and t1.Buyer = t2.Buyer 
                          and t1.[usage] = t2.[usage]
                          and t1.[Item Code] = t2.[Item Code]
                          and t1.[Item Name] = t2.[Item Name]
ORDER BY Coalesce(t1.[Customer], t2.[Customer])
```

On a side note if you have vertical partition it'l be a lot better if you create a key to join the partition that is shorter, for example you can divide the key section and add a fake ID to relate to the other partition, something like

```
ID | Customer | Buyer | Usage | Item Code | Item Name

ID | Month1 | Month2

ID | Month3 | Month4
```